# What is the proper way to define an array of values for the IN operator in Active Record

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I need to search my data for rows who's value is contained in an array of strings.  What is the proper way to do this in Active Record?

For example, say I have this array:

```
["fluffy", "spot"]
```

I want the SQL to look something like this:

```
select * FROM Pets WHERE name IN ('fluffy', 'spot')
```

The following works:

```
list = ["fluffy", "spot"].map { |x| "'#{x}'" }.join(', ')
Pet.where("name in (#{list})")
```

Obviously this is a bad idea.  What is the correct method to do this?  Is there a way to use parameters in this way, or does Active Record have a special method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = ["fluffy", "spot"]    
Pet.where(:name => list)
```